# Dot in file sizes replaced by the word "dot"

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, download

Just had a PC in where all the periods in file sizes have been replaced by either "dot" or d.

Such as a 100gb drive with 20.8gb remaining would be something like: 20dot8GB Remaining. This also happens with file sizes when downloading, it would show up as 856d7kb downloaded.

This doesn't happen everywhere, but it seems to only happen in file sizes, and not other uses of a dot.

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbols Windows uses as the decimal point are controlled by regional settings.

Please try the following:

- Go to the Control Panel
- Choose **Region** (Windows 8) or **Region and Language** (Windows 7)
- Click the **Formats** tab
- Click **Additional settings...**
- Click the **Numbers** tab

  [image: Number formats]
- Change the value in the **Decimal symbol** field to a `.`, or click **Reset**